# Docker container not able to start on M1 mac

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose.yml file which has the following service:

```
services:
  main_db:
    container_name: ${DB_CONTAINER_NAME}
    build: ./docker/main_db
    ports:
     - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/opt/mssql
```

When I used the older MacBook Pro, I was able to use this docker-compose and I was able to run

> docker-compose --file docker-compose.yml up --detach --build --force-recreate

in order to get all containers running.

Now I switched over to M1 Mac and when I try to run my container, I am getting the following error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.

I found a bit of information how to run [SQL server on M1 Mac here](https://medium.com/geekculture/docker-express-running-a-local-sql-server-on-your-m1-mac-8bbc22c49dc9)

But I was not able to convert this change to docker-compose.yml

I am also not using the Microsoft Azure sql edge. Instead, I am using some custom built docker container which is using Microsoft Azure sql edge and also installing the database configuration on top of it.

Can someone advice how can I improve my docker-compose in order to start running this mssql container?

Comment: Presumably your `docker/main_db/Dockerfile` has some kind of init script to load some data. Is that waiting for the SQL Server to start before trying to connect?

Comment: Possibly related to my issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68500448/docker-cypress-container-failing-due-to-qemu-error-on-m1-chip